# Whats wrong? Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

SyntaxError: invalid syntax. when executing, it does not work, create groups by continent, writes that = invalid, what should be put?

def country_kl(country):

```
if country = ['United States', 'Mexico', 'Canada', 'Bahamas', 'Chile', 'Brazil', 'Colombia','British Virgin Islands'
,'Peru','Uruguay','Turks and Caicos Islands','Cambodia','Bermuda','Argentina']: 
    return '1'
elif country = ['France', 'Spain', 'Germany', 'Switzerland', 'Belgium', 'United Kingdom', 'Austria', 'Italy', 'Swaziland'
,'Russia' , 'Sweden','Czechia','Monaco','Denmark','Poland','Norway','Netherlands','Portugal','Turkey','Finland',
'Ukraine','Andorra','Hungary','Greece','Romania','Slovakia','Liechtenstein','Guernsey','Ireland']:
    return '2'
elif country = ['India','China', 'Singapore', 'Hong Kong', 'Australia', 'Japan']:
    return '3'
elif country = ['United Arab Emirates',
                     'Thailand','Malaysia','New Zealand','South Korea','Philippines','Taiwan','Israel','Vietnam','Cayman Islands',
                     'Kazakhstan' ,'Georgia','Bahrain','Nepal','Qatar','Oman','Lebanon']:
    return '3'
else :
    return '4'
```

Comment: are you sure that you want to check equality between single string and array? probably you want to check for inclusion like `country in [...]`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One more error in your code is that you used a **single** "=", what
actually means **substitution**.

To **compare** two values use "==" (**double** "=").

But of course, to check whether a value of a variable is **contained**
in a list you have to use *in* operator, just as *Ilya* suggested in his comment.

Another, more readable and elegant solution is:

1. Create a dictionary, where the key is country name and the
   value is your expected result for this country. Something like:

   ```
   countries = {'United States': '1', 'Mexico': '1', 'France': '2', 'Spain': '2',
       'India': '3', 'China': '3', 'Singapore': '3'}
   ```

   (include other countries too).
2. Look up this dictionary, with default value of `'4'`, which you
   used in your code:

   ```
   result = countries.get(country, default='4')
   ```

And by the way: Your question and code have nothing to do with *Pandas*.
You use ordinary, *pythonic* list and (as I suppose) a string variable.

But since you marked your question also with *Pandas* tag,
I came up also with a *pandasonic* solution:

1. Create a *Series* from the above dictionary:

   ```
   ctr = pd.Series(countries.values(), index=countries.keys())
   ```
2. Lookup this *Series*, also with a default value:

   ```
   result = ctr.get(country, default='4')
   ```